# Logic inside EPiServer Pages and Blocks

Tags: model-view-controller, episerver

I have an instance where I'm using an interface on my Model as a means of filtering my blocks and pages for lists (i.e. select all blocks or pages with "IMyInterface"), but along with that is a requirement to convert to another type for display (i.e. list all blocks/pages, then for each block/page, convert to "MyDisplayType" and pass to a partial view)

My question: Is logic inside my EPiServer Pages and Blocks (my models) discouraged?

Edit in response to @Ted:
An attribute on the PageViewModel won't work, attribute == "include me", something else does the "act of inclusion" (that is what I meant by filtering), and as I have an interface on my model, it's natural to me to have logic associated with the attribute in the model as well (as the attribute is on the model). If i don't have logic in my class that has the attribute, then I need a "helper class" to host the code that I feel is best left in the Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, but I would say the more common approach is to have specific view model types.

So, your views would have `@model IPageViewModel<SomePageType>` instead of just `@model SomePageType`.

In your controller you would then `return View(new SomePageViewModel(currentPage))` instead of `return View(currentPage)`.

Same principle applies to other content types (blocks, media, etc).

I would stay away from logic in the content types themselves, except for specific methods such as `SetDefaultValues`.

In your particular case it sounds like maybe you should add the content list as a property to the view model instance originally passed, and then enumerate that property in the view to render each item using a partial view?

**Edit:** I think interfaces work great for "grouping" content types, for example to get all `IArticle` pages, regardless of exact content type. I usually put logic for retrieving collections of content (e.g. `all article pages`) in repository classes or controller action methods. Of course such logic could, in addition to filtering by interface, also reflect attributes.

Comment: thanks for your response, I've updated my question in response.

Comment: @Nnoel: Updated my answer in response. :)

Comment: Thank you, you've given me something to consider. So hard to find decent discussion of this sort of thing, though I realise it's all opinions really.